# Django - Extending user profile not showing fileds in chenge form

Tags: python, django, extend

I want to extend the user model in django adding new fields and of course be able to manage it through the admin pages.
I created a CustomUser model in django extending AbstractUser and added some extra fields, created a UserCustomCreateForm and UserCustomChangeForm to manage the creation and change and then registered a CustomUserAdmin that extend the UserAdmin adding the two forms.
In admin, it seems to work fine when create a new users but unfortunately the new fields don't appear on the change view.

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks

here is the models.py

```
 users/models.py
# Create your models here.

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    # add additional fields in here
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, verbose_name='Indirizzo')
    house_phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, verbose_name='Telefono')
    mobile_phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, verbose_name='Cellulare')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name
```

here the forms

```
# users/forms.py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from .models import CustomUser
from django import forms

class UserCustomCreateForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta(UserCreationForm):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name',
                  'address', 'house_phone', 'mobile_phone')


class UserCustomChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = (
                  'username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name',
                  'address', 'house_phone', 'mobile_phone')
```

And here the admin.py

```
# users/admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .forms import UserCustomCreateForm, UserCustomChangeForm
from .models import CustomUser
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm


class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = UserCustomCreateForm
    form = UserCustomChangeForm
    change_form = UserCustomChangeForm
    model = CustomUser

    add_fieldsets = (
     ( "Dati di Accesso", {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields':('username', 'password1', 'password2',)
     }
     ),
     ( "Informazioni Personali", {
        'classes': ('wide',),
        'fields': ( 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name',
                  'address', 'house_phone', 'mobile_phone')
     } ),
    )
    list_display = ['email', 'username',]

admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

Comment: I think you need to set `fieldsets` also, most likely the fieldsets in `UserAdmin` are being used.

Comment: Top! That was it, added 


fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name',
                                         'address', 'house_phone', 'mobile_phone')}),
        (_('Permissions'), {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser',
                                       'groups', 'user_permissions')}),
        (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
    )


in CustomUserAdmin and worked fine.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

In your code of admin.py file change `add_fieldsets = [...]` to `fieldsets = [...]`.

The `fieldsets` defines the fieldsets for both views (add, change). The `add_fieldsets` define the result only for the add view.